# How to get list out of the method and return?

Tags: java, android, callback

I want to get the arraylist that i've logged in the onNewsReceived method and return it via getNews method.

Code:

```
    @Override
    public ArrayList<News> getNews() {


        getNewsDataSource(new NewsListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNewsReceived(ArrayList<News> newsList) {

                Log.i("news:", newsList.toString());
                // how do i return the newsList below

            }
        });


        return newsList;

    }
}
```

Comment: You must call a callback inside onNewsReceived instead

Comment: frankly speaking using a callback only i got the data from volley's onResponse callback method to here, can you elaborate on how a callback would further help me get the data and return it via getNews method ?

Comment: Instead of calling getNews (that will be async by the way) you need inside onResponde call the method that called getNews back

Comment: getNews is from the interface which the class implements that contains getNewsDataSource method. do you wanna take a look at the whole class?

Comment: If you isong MVP you have the getNews at the Presenter and you need a method like onNewsReceived on View, so you can call the view method from inside the presenter (at onResponse)

Comment: yes, i'm using MVP and its my first application with the same, i've getNews at the model's interface and you mean method like onNewsReceived should be in view interface ? i guess i've literally lost you, do you mind taking a look at my code : https://github.com/iamarjun/HackerNews

Comment: Yes, on MVP contract methods always returns void. They can call the other side with the appropriate callback, I took a look but i'm not on mood now to write such an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make NewsDataSource class abstract and method `getNews()` also. now just call `getNews()` method inside the `getNewsDataSource()` method. Extend NewsDataSource class to your calling class and override the `getNews()` method. Or you can send your calling class NewsListener listener.

Comment: thanks for the reply but making NewDataSource class abstarct would break my controller/presenter plus getNews() method resides in the interface NewsSourceInterface  and making it abstract is redundant.
Also by calling you mean the activity where getNews() method is suppose to return the newsList ??